# Python: list indices must be integer, not str, when loading str array

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to load a big multidimensional array, first with strings (because stuff like 08 and 09 are registered as different type tokens) and then mapping them to integers.

```
strarray = [['08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08']
            ['49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00']
            ['81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65']
            ['52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91']
            ['22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80']
            ['24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50']
            ['32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70']
            ['67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21']
            ['24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72']
            ['21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95']
            ['78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92']
            ['16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57']
            ['86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58']
            ['19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40']
            ['04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66']
            ['88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69']
            ['04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36']
            ['20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16']
            ['20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54']
            ['01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48']]

numarray = map(int, strarray)

print numarray
```

However, when I try to run this, it gives me the error "list indices must be integer, not string"

Why is this happening?

Comment: your `starray` is not a valid list`

Comment: Add the commas in the end of each line. Then your code will show another error... Hint: split each element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list if list of strings, so you need to unpack items of sub list, split them and apply int to each. Also it looks like you forgot to put commas to split top level list items. Try this:

```
strarray = [['08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08'],
        ['49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00'],
        ['81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65'],
        ...]
numaarray = [map(int, subL[0].split()) for subL in strarray]
```